# Can a universal derailleur hanger be a suitable long term solution?

Tags: derailleur, hanger

I've recently snapped my derailleur hanger for an old *Apollo Raceline Peleton* road bike. Have had no luck sourcing a replacement that fits, and neither have local bike shop.

Has anyone been in a similar situation and used a universal derailleur hanger to suffice?

Could something like this work? https://problemsolversbike.com/products/drivetrain/universal_-_21655

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you try http://wheelsmfg.com?

Comment: Yeah no luck, contacted apollo too

Comment: The pictures of your snapped derailleur hanger of this old Apollo Raceline Peleton road bike would greatly help with giving an answer.

Comment: @Mike not the greatest quality pics I know but bike is not with my atm unfortunately. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: A serious LBS (local bike store) is most likely to have a chart to find a matching hanger. Else remove the hanger from bike and derailleur, place both ends on a sheet of paper and draw the outline. You might be lucky on a site like this one (googled for 10 seconds): https://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hangers.html

Comment: @Carel - this one https://wheelsmfg.com/derailleur-hangers/derailleur-hanger-1.html seems to fit, though the price is a rip-off unless the thing is made of gold or titanium.

Comment: @Mike *though the price is a rip-off* Not when you consider the cost of designing and manufacturing probably at most a few hundred of them, if it's that many.

Comment: @AndrewHenle - your justification is correct, however look at the link in my answer, the hangers from Marwi there are between 20% and 30% of the price of WheelsMFG. How would you explain that?

Comment: @Mike I didn't characterize their prices, so I don't have an opinion to explain.  You do - you labelled someone with the pejorative term "rip-off".

Comment: Its the capitalistic world, If cost-plus price is less than value add to the customer, a deal can be done that benefits both parties. Final price sits somewhere between those two or transaction does not happen.

Answer (score 1):

The particular derailleur hanger you linked is not going to fit your bike, I'm afraid. It's more of use with the bicycles that have the almost horizontal forward-facing dropouts.

What you can do is take the remainings of the hanger you have, inspect it for any markings and on a page like https://www.internet-bikes.com/versnellingen/derailleurhangers (I'm not affiliated with them, though I buy my parts there) find the closest match to your broken part.

Or even take your search a step further and browse the webpage of the manufacturer of those hangers and match your part with their catalogue: http://www.marwi-eu.com/gh-catalogue.php (again, not affiliated).

Good luck!

Comment: The instructions for the problem solver universal hanger directly indicates it can be used in both horizontal and vertical drop outs.